# Multiple definitions and undefined references

Tags: c++

My C++ code gets many "multiple definition" errors when compiled. A minimal example for my situation is:

```
//testA.h
#ifndef __FILEA_H_INCLUDED__
#define __FILEA_H_INCLUDED__

int A;
int B;

#endif

//testB.h
#ifndef __FILEB_H_INCLUDED__
#define __FILEB_H_INCLUDED__

int C;
int D;

#endif

//testA.cpp
#include "testA.h"

//testB.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "testA.h"
#include "testB.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << C << std::endl;
}
```

Prepending "extern" to variable declarations solves these "multiple definition" errors but introduces "undefined reference" errors. I have tried everything I can think of to solve this - but obviously I am doing something wrong.

In case you wonder, in my real application I *need* the variables to be treated as global variables.

Comment: Use `extern int A;` in header files, and put the definitions in a `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare global variables in `.h` file, and define them in `.cpp` file.

> In testA.h

`extern int A;`

> In testA.cpp

`int A;`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know a redeclaration in the .cpp was needed.

Comment: @Jaeya It's NOT a redeclaration, but a definition. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) for their difference.

Comment: Finally I get the difference :) Thanks!